# How do I get the Nautilus link/icon to show in file manager in Ubuntu 18.04.1?

Tags: nautilus

I recently updated to Ubuntu 18.04.1. Nautilus file manager has no Nautilus shell icon to allow me to access root files as in the attached pic from https://fosspost.org/reviews/distributions/ubuntu-18-04-review-an-interesting-lts-release. How do I get the Nautilus shell icon, or link, on Nautilus file manager?

Comment: Open "Other Locations".